# how to generate multi dimensional grid from a system of multi-variate inequalites

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

I have a system of 6 inequalities in the form of (rational but not necessarily linear):1+x1x2>x3; x4>(1+x5)x6; x3/x4>1-x2;... and more.

Now I need to generate a grid of (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7) that satisfies all 6 inequalities so that I can iterate over it.
What I mean by "grid" is a set of points that 1. satisfy all these inequalities, 2. reasonably span the subspace confined by them.
For example, a three dimensional grid defined by x+y=<6, x-y>=1 and 2=<y=<4 is: ((3,2),(4,2),(3,3),(4,3))

I know that this can certainly be done by finding the extreme values of x1,...,x7 individually, and then generate a mother grid by spanning the cartesian product of these individual bounds, then select from this mother grid by checking one by one whether each of the points satisfy the 6 conditions. But this method would potentially have to check way more points than the right ones.

The most preferred solution is in sympy, but other Python package would be fine too.

Obviously sympy doesn't allow reducing multivariate inequalities, but since I only need to generate a grid, maybe there's an indirect way to achieve this?

Somebody mentioned elsewhere that linprog from scipy is able to reduce multivariate inequalities, but it seems only able to solve linear inequalities. I also don't get how to get from an optimization problem (what linprog solves) to an inequality reduction problem.

Comment: Do the coordinates all need to be integers? Also does "nonlinear" mean polynomial or something else?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Oscar. I don't get what you mean by "coordinates being all integers". These variables are allowed to take positive real numbers, not just integers. As for being polynomials, if x*y-x**2 counts as a polynomial, then yes--there will be multiplicative terms between variables.

Comment: Please show all six inequalities

Comment: What should be done about cases where the border cannot be defined by a straight line? Your example seems to be asking for the points of a polygon which define the borders of the inequality, but many nonlinear inequalities will have curved borders. [Example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x1*x2+%3C+1%2C+x1%3E0%2C+x2%3E0)